# Why do knot cobordisms result in functoriality with respect to knot homologies so often?

Tags: knot-theory

Why do knot cobordisms result in functoriality with respect to knot homologies so often?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask

Comment: I think Neil is saying you should have some more backround information. Can you give some examples of this phenomenon?  How did it arise in your work?  You say often - can you explain some situations where it fails, and give your thoughts on how these situations are different?

Answer (score 1):

Because the knot homology theories are TQFTs!

This definition is taken from [[1](http://www.math.ru.nl/%7Emueger/TQFT/At.pdf)]: [image]

Knot homology theories are (1+1)-dimensional TQFTs: links are 1-manifolds, and cobordisms between them are 2-manifolds.